# Laravel 5.1 deployement Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages

Tags: php, centos7, linode

When I am trying to deploy my laravel project and do a php composer.phar install I get this annoying error. I pulled in my project via git with a git clone. And when I surf to my domainname I would like to see my app obviously :). I've installed a correct version of apache, mysql and php. Everything is up and running.

error:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file 
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- Installation request for brianmcdo/image-palette dev-master -> satisfiable by brianmcdo/image-palette[dev-master].
- brianmcdo/image-palette dev-master requires ext-gd * -> the requested PHP extension gd is missing from your system.
Problem 2
- Installation request for phpunit/phpunit 4.8.18 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[4.8.18].
- phpunit/phpunit 4.8.18 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
```

When I try to install php-gd or dom I get this error:

```
Error: php56w-common conflicts with php-common-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64
```

my php version:(php -v)

```
PHP 5.6.14 (cli) (built: Oct 16 2015 07:11:57)
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2015, by Zend Technologies
```

results of rpm -qa | grep php:

```
php56w-mbstring-5.6.14-2.w7.x86_64
php56w-cli-5.6.14-2.w7.x86_64
php56w-common-5.6.14-2.w7.x86_64
php56w-5.6.14-2.w7.x86_64
php56w-opcache-5.6.14-2.w7.x86_64
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing php-common-5.4* and rerun the installation.
You must remove old PHP packages before installing replacement.

Comment: Could you help me out with how I exactly do this? I am kinda new to deployement/linux

Comment: I've tried something like this yum remove php-common-5.4* but it says no match for argument 5.4* no packages marked for removal

Comment: So try the whole package name  - sudo yum remove php-common-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64

Comment: I have fixed it and was able to do a php composer.phar for my laravel project but when I go to my domain I still only see the apache testing screen I've also restarted httpd

Comment: edit your httpd.conf properly. please see the following https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-laravel-4-on-a-centos-6-vps regarding the httpd config

Comment: I've worked with a virtualhost file in /etc/http/conf.d/appname.conf If I add a index.php file with a simple phpinfo() in it everything works but when I remove the index file it goes back to the standard apache page. I've done eveything what they said in the link you've provided and unfortunately I still can't see my laravel app.